# Why is this code skipping every other input line

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to loop over the data via a regex and parsing each line by the date (i.e. 7/9/2019). However, the results omit every other line in the input data.

Tried this on Windows and Mac (Terminal shell) to the same behaviour consistently.

```
my $file;

{
    local $/ = undef;
    $file = <DATA>;
}

while ($file =~ m/(\d\/\d\/\d{4}.*?)\d\/\d\/\d{4}/gs) {
    print "*$1*\n";
}

__DATA__
9/7/2019 20:35:17,dog
9/7/2019 21:06:16,cat
9/7/2019 22:32:15,parrot
9/7/2019 22:32:15,snail
9/7/2019
```

I expect the following:

```
*9/7/2019 20:35:17,dog*
*9/7/2019 21:06:16,cat*
*9/7/2019 22:32:15,parrot*
*9/7/2019 22:32:15,snail*
```

but instead get the following:

```
*9/7/2019 20:35:17,dog
*
*9/7/2019 22:32:15,parrot
*
```

Comment: Because you consume the end `\d\/\d\/\d{4}` pattern part. Try `while ($file =~ m/(\d\/\d\/\d{4}.*?)(?=\s*\d\/\d\/\d{4})/gs)`. Or, replace `\s*` with `\R` to match the line break sequence. See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/cw1A9t).

Comment: So you're trying to get each line if it's followed by a date on the next line (-> positive lookahead)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thank you so much - works!

Comment: I just saw at Wiktor's comment right after I posted my answer. But both of our solutions should return the correct value you're looking for.

Comment: @spaceboy2020 Could you mark my answer as the accepted answer so this question will be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not encapsulating the end of your pattern. Change your while loop to:

```
 while ($file =~ m/(\d\/\d\/\d{4}.*?)(?=\R\d\/\d\/\d{4})/gs) {
    print "*$1*\n";
}
```

That should work for you. Test it out at: https://rextester.com/l/perl_online_compiler

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matches two dates, so the next match will proceed from there, effectively skipping the line.

There's no point in checking if the next line starts with a date, so you could use

```
while (<DATA>) {
   next if !m{^(\d+/\d+/\d+)};

   print "*$1*\n";
}
```

If you weren't reading from a file:

```
while ($file =~ m{^(\d+/\d+/\d+)}mg) {
   print "*$1*\n";
}
```

If every line starts with a date, you could even use

```
while (<DATA>) {
   my @fields = split;
   print "*$fields[0]*\n";
}
```

If you weren't reading from a file:

```
while ($file =~ /^(.*)/mg) {
   my @fields = split;
   print "*$1*\n";
}
```

The lack of `/s` means that `.` won't match a line feed, which means it won't match beyond the end of the line.